# Despite having values in Database, Debugger shows null value in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, firebase-realtime-database

As you can see that I have data in my database and `userId` and `profilePhotoUrl` has value but in my debugger, it is showing null, as you can see in the below images. Can anyone tell me about why this is happening?

[image: dede]

[image]

Here is the Code, As you can see the username and phone number can be seen in the debugger but userId and profilephoto values are null

```
public class UsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<ProfileInfo> minfo;
public static final String USER_ID = "userid";
Context context;

public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ProfileInfo> minfo) {
    this.context = context;
    this.minfo = minfo;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_item, parent, false);
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    view.setLayoutParams(lp);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ProfileInfo profileInfo = minfo.get(position);
    holder.username.setText(profileInfo.getUserName());
    holder.phoneNumber.setText(profileInfo.getPhoneNumber());
    Picasso.get().load(profileInfo.getProfilePhotoUrl()).
            centerCrop().
            into(holder.profileImage);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MessageLayout.class);
            intent.putExtra(USER_ID, profileInfo.getUserId());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return minfo.size();
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView username;
    TextView phoneNumber;
    CircleImageView profileImage;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user);
        phoneNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
        profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.circleProfileImage);
        relativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

    }
}
}
```

Here is the code where I am trying to fetch the data from the database.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_layout);

    username = findViewById(R.id.displayUsername);
    profileImage = findViewById(R.id.circledp);
    currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    recieverId = intent.getStringExtra(UsersAdapter.USER_ID);

    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserInfo").child(recieverId);
    chatDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chats");
    db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ProfileInfo info = dataSnapshot.getValue(ProfileInfo.class);
            username.setText(info.getUserName());
            Glide.with(MessageLayout.this).load(info.getProfilePhotoUrl()).into(profileImage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

**ProfileInfo Class Code**

```
public class ProfileInfo {

String userName, profilePhotoUrl, phoneNumber, userId;

public ProfileInfo() {}

public ProfileInfo(String userName, String profilePhotoUrl, String phoneNumber, String userId) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.profilePhotoUrl = profilePhotoUrl;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.userId = userId;
}

public ProfileInfo(String userName, String phoneNumber) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}


public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public String getProfilePhotoUrl() {
    return profilePhotoUrl;
}
}
```

Comment: "Can anyone tell me about why this is happening?" - possibly a lot of people could help, with the relevant code in your question.

Comment: @MarkKeen I have added the code please check it out.

Comment: @HarshAshra I think that your adapter code looks fine but this not where you fetch the values from your database. You should post the code of your database fetching. Here, as long as minfo comes in right, your result will be displayed.

Comment: @bengongon97 I have added the code where I am trying to fetch the data.

Comment: Please add the content of your `ProfileInfo` class too. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Added.

Comment: If you try to use `Log.d("TAG", infogetProfilePhotoUrl())` inside `onDataChange()`, is it something printed out in the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `receiverID` is correct, try like this:

```
db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //the data
        String userName = dataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue(String.class);
        String profilePhotoUrl = dataSnapshot.child("profilePhotoUrl").getValue(String.class);

        //set the data
        username.setText(userName);
        Glide.with(MessageLayout.this).load(profilePhotoUrl).into(profileImage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

I think your `receiverID` variable is null, make sure you are passing it correctly by intent. Try to log it to and see if its null.

Comment: The problem is that it is throwing null value for userID and profilephotoUrl, But in my database I had value for both of these.

Comment: did you try my method.

Comment: db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserInfo").child(recieverId); 
This is where I am getting error. The code will not reach till addValueEventListener as it will throw an error before it reaches your code.

Comment: look also show me the code where you initialize the `UsersAdapter`